# Possible to use Lombok @AllArgsConstructor annotation with Cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber, lombok

I am currently trying to add Cucumber tests to a Java project that uses Lombok's `@AllArgsConstructor` for constructor dependency injection.

Generally, Cucumber uses cucumber-picocontainer for dependency injection
it seems. Would it be possible to use `@AllArgsConstructor` instead - this project has fairly long call stacks, throughout which `@AllArgsConstructor` 
is constantly used. Switching to cucumber-picocontainer for constructor dependency injection seems like a lot of hard work.